# how to clear button asp buttons from client side using jquery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

*Add, Update, Clear, Delete, Exit*
these are the five buttons and one more in the Grid (Edit).
Normally *Add, Clear, Exit* will be visible to add new record (*Update and Clear* is disabled).
Now, when the *Edit* button is pressed i need to disable *Add, Clear* and (*Update, Delete*) needs to be enabled.

```
$get("<%=imbAdd.ClientID%>").style.visibility = "hidden";
document.getElementById('imbClear').style.visibility = "hidden";
```

I have tried my best

```
$get("<%=imbUpdate.ClientID%>").style.visibility = "visible"; 
$get("<%=imbDelete.ClientID%>").style.visibility = "visible";
```

I have done this in server side now i am trying to do it in client side.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: shortcut for document.getElementById('value') and Sys.Application.findComponent('value')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use:

```
 $("#<%=imbAdd.ClientID%>").css('visibility', 'hidden');


 $("#<%=imbDelete.ClientID%>").css('visibility', 'visible');
```

You can also use:

```
$("#<%=imbAdd.ClientID%>").hide();


$("#<%=imbDelete.ClientID%>").show();
```

Comment: 'hidden' is working fine, 'visible' is not responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, Hope it will work:

**to disable**

```
document.getElementById("imbClear").disabled = true;
```

**to enable**

```
document.getElementById("imbClear").disabled = false;
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: Unable to set value of the property 'disabled': object is null or undefined, is there any problem in my script

Comment: Are you setting button id as "imbClear" and is this button is scope of this page. Please double check your dependent code... Below mentioned is sample code for easy understanding:

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button id="myBtn">My Button</button>

<p>Click the button below to disable the button above.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled=true;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

```
$("selector").css('disabled',true)
```